# Ways to speed up a LIKE %foo% search across multiple fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm looking for a way to do a fast-as-possible incomplete-word `LIKE "%foo%"` lookup across two tables in a MySQL database.

Let's say I have two tables, Boxes and Objects, where each Box contains multiple Objects. What we want to do is find the ID of the box (Box.id) by matching a search string against `Box.name` OR `Object.name`.

To give you a picture of the scale we're dealing with, Boxes contains ~500,000 entries, while Objects contains ~200,000 entries.

Every Object is in a Box, not every Box contains Objects. I have indices on `Box.id`, `Object.id`, and `Object.box_id`.

**Why?**

I need this data fast (200ms) so I can offer suggestions as a user types a search. The data set is essentially static, updated en masse yearly. `Box.id` will never, ever change. I'm using an initial wildcard because the matching word may not start at the start of the string- for example, `"flo"` needs to suggest `"cake flour"` as well as `"flour"`.

**What I've tried:**

**Doing a LEFT JOIN between the two tables:**

`SELECT b.id, b.name, o.name FROM boxes b LEFT JOIN objects o ON (b.id = o.box_id) WHERE ((b.name LIKE "%test str%") OR (o.name LIKE "%test str%")) LIMIT 10;`

Time to search: `3900ms.`

**Denormalizing everything to one lookup table:**

`SELECT n.id, n.box_name, n.object_name from lookup_table n WHERE ((n.box_name LIKE "%test str%") OR (n.object_name LIKE "%test str%")) LIMIT 10;`

Time to search: `1100ms`.

Getting rid of that JOIN clearly does wonders; however, this is still too slow. Ideally, this should take 200ms or less. Does anyone have any insight into how to optimize partial-word match queries?

Comment: Your problem is that queries with wildcards can never run efficiently if the wildcard is the first character.

Comment: What is the 200ms figure based upon?  Is there a reason to believe that scanning 700,000 entries is going to be done in that period of time?  Is there a reason to believe that the search you specify can be done without a full scan of the tables?

Comment: 200ms is the time it takes for a user to feel like an app is "laggy". I need this for a typeahead. I know searching 700k fields dumbly isn't going to be very fast- but there have to be ways to optimize this. Incomplete matches on the typeahead would be very nice. Google does this- although mere mortals don't have the processing horsepower they've got.

Comment: @schnauss Google uses a lot of horsepower, sure, but the bigger thing going for them is using a system intended for this sort of thing. MySQL is **not** good at full-text searching like this. Look into stuff like ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into full text indexing. You shoud not be querying with a wildcard as the first character in a production system.

Do not denormalize as there are other problems associated with doing that including espcially problems with dat integrity other performance problems caused by tables being too wide, issues when the one-one relationship becomes one-to-many, other affected code that will break, etc. Joins are good. You should want joins, databases like joins. Of course you should make sure the fields you join on are indexed.

Comment: Apparently, while FULLTEXT doesn't support full wildcards, it does support prefixes and suffixes: `SELECT * FROM lookup_table WHERE MATCH (box_name,object_name) AGAINST ('+test +str*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` returns everything I need with a query time of 40ms!

Comment: FULLTEXT does not support '+*str*'.  Also, be aware of the 'min word length' setting.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a JS app in a UI, look for packages that do what you want.  They are tuned for good speed, and do not depend on SQL.